# Use Middleware for some controllers

Tags: c#, middleware, asp.net-core-3.1

In my ASP Net Core application I need to apply a custom Middleware only for specific controller.

I found this example

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    app.UseMiddleware();
});
```

Is this the correct way?

And how can I check if the request path Contains a specific path instead of starts with?

Answer (score 15):

(you are) "close" ... but with a few tweaks.. you can accomplish what you want:

You have

```
 app.UseMiddleware();
```

You most likely want to specify ~which middleware to use.  See "MyMiddlewareOne" example below.

Below is tested with Asp.Net Core 3.1.      ( I think I was at 3.1.407, but 3.1 or above should be ok )

simple version:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


public class Startup
{

    public void Configure(ILogger<Startup> logger, IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

    {


        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddlewareOne>();
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        { blah blah blah } );



    }
}
```

Now, you should be careful on how complex you make the rules.

But you can do something like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("apiwideopen/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}

[Route("apisecure/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyNeedsToBeSecureController : ControllerBase
{
}



        app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/apisecure"), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddlewareOne>();
        });
```

You can also do this to encapsulate rules.

```
        app.UseWhen(context => this.CheckMoreAdvancedRules(context), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddlewareOne>();
        });



    private bool CheckMoreAdvancedRules(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext ctx)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        if (null != ctx && ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/apisecure"))
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }

        if(!returnValue)
        {
            /* do whatever you want here */
            /* if the moon is blue at midnight (then) returnValue = true; */
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Lastly, you want to pay attention between

"MapWhen" and "UseWhen"

See:

[Registering a middleware while using MapWhen for branching to run it just for a set of endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308273/registering-a-middleware-while-using-mapwhen-for-branching-to-run-it-just-for-a/61308412#61308412)

also see this article:

https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core

Answer (score 4):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42583583/11306392) suggests if you require context of MVC you should prefer filters to middleware.

Also [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-filters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) you can find and example how to apply filters to the specific controller.