# How to skip specific routes in ASP.NET Core middleware?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, middleware

I need to run some code in middleware only but if route contains speciffic value.

Comment: This will probably already answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776177/214977

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   if(!(new string[] { "/api/", "/sitemaps/", "ads.txt" }.Any(context.Request.Path.Value.Contains)))
   {
      //Do some stuff if route not contains values from array
   }
   await next();
});
```